# How to remove backslashes from QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

Using `QNetworkManager` `get` method I am receiving a json from a url.
Doing: `qDebug()<<(QString)reply->readAll();` the result is:

```
"\r\n[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Jhon\",\"surname\":\"Snow\",\"phone\":\"358358358\"}]"
```

So I am doing `strReply = strReply.simplified();` , and the result is:

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Jhon\",\"surname\":\"Snow\",\"phone\":\"358358358\"}]"
```

But I can't use that to parse it like a Json to use it in my qt program.
So I think I need to remove every backslashes `\` and obtain:

```
"[{"id":"1","name":"Jhon","surname":"Snow","phone":"348348348"}]"
```

I tried `strReply.remove(QRegExp( "\\\" ) );` but any odd concatenation of `\` is causing the interpreter to think at every thing that comes after the last `\` as a string.

Comment: There are at least 5 simple, reasonable answers. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because I tried them with no success.

Comment: I don't have Qt now but try this: `string ans = str.remove( QRegExp( "\\\" ) );`

Comment: You don't want to remove bsckslahes, you want to unescape a JavaScript string. That's a quite different problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need to remove them? They are escape characters

Comment: What do you really want to do?

Comment: Editing the question to explain better, maybe the problem is as @MatteoItalia suggested

Comment: @BonjeFir the problem with that is that the compiler consider everything that comes after the last \ as a string, so it prompts error

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro Check four backslashes. Two of them for match pattern in regex and Two of them to determine a backslash in string. `QRegExp( "\\\\" )`

Comment: Have you verified that the backslashes are actually in the string? If you're trying to print a string using `qDebug()`, you need to use `qDebug().noquote()` if you don't want `qDebug()` to artificially insert backslashes in the ouput.

Comment: @NikosC. yes! with noquote() it printed without any king of carriage

Comment: That means the string doesn't have backslashes in it, thus there's nothing to remove. You can also test it by writing the QString to a file. Open the file in a text editor. If the backslashes aren't there, there's nothing for you to do; there's no backslashes in the string. It's just `qDebug()` that's adding them.

Comment: I'll second what @NikosC.just said: the backslashes are not in your string at all. It would make it an invalid json. You see them **because** you are printing the string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, so it's something else.

Comment: Try [QJsonDocument::fromJson](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) with the string you receive as it is.

Comment: It wasn't working because I was accessing the model where I wanted to save the json data with uppercase attributes name but the header was defined in lower case. Sorry for bothering all of you. Anyway I learned something today. Thank You

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably running into `qDebug`'s feature that escapes quotes and newlines. Your string most probably doesn't actually have any backslashes in it.

When you're trying to print a string using `qDebug()`, you need to use `qDebug().noquote()` if you don't want qDebug() to artificially insert backslashes in the output.

So your string should be fine. It doesn't have any backslashes in it at all.

Comment: I'm a little late here, but it should be mentioned that `QString::simplified()` can be also used to remove escape characters such as `\n` and `\r` (anything that for which `QString::isSpace()` returns true) and replacing sequences of whitespaces with a single whitespace.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#remove) You can remove a character with remove function

```
QString t = "Ali Baba";
t.remove(QChar('a'), Qt::CaseInsensitive);
// Will result "li Bb"
```

You can put '\\' instead of 'a' to remove your backslashes from your QString

Comment: Doesen't work with backslashes because they are considered escape. Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro Answer edited , What about '\\' ?

Comment: doesnt work in my case, I'll explain better in question. Thank you